# rake aborted:PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm on Cloud9 Ubuntu Template and I installed postgres. I'm getting an error when I try to do a "rake db:migrate".

```
rake aborted:PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Related settings in my database.yml file

```
default: &default
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      pool: 5
      username: <%= ENV['USERNAME'] %>
      password: <%= ENV['PASSWORD'] %>
      host:     <%= ENV['IP'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development
```

Comment: are you sure ENV['USERNAME'] and ENV['PASSWORD'] is set?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Cloud9 issue. I refer https://community.c9.io/t/fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied-error-after-setting-up-postgrsql-on-rails/2206/2

Run below commands on your c9 terminal.

```
$ source ~/.profile
$ rake db:create
$ rake db:migrate
```

It works for me.